# Copy value of a dynamic cell to another sheet on edit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I am trying to copy the value of a dynamic cell into a specific cell on another sheet upon edits being done in the first sheet.

Example:
Whenever cell A5 and B3 and C2 are edited on sheet 'work', it should take the current value of cell B1 and copy it to cell C5 on sheet 'overview'.

Here is the code I have so far, but it somehow does not work. What am I missing here?

```
    function onEdit2() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "work") {
    var r =s.getActiveCell() ;
    if(r.getCell('A5') || r.getCell('B3') || r.getCell('C2') {
      var b =  s.getCell('B1') ;
      var uo = SpreadsheetApp.getSheet('overview')
      b.copyTo(uo.getCell('C5'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use a function/formula in the google sheet?

Comment: I don't think so, as I need a stamp of the dynamic cell upon the edit of another. If I'd just use ='work'!B1 it'd constantly update the cell. But I need to know what value it had when I edit one of my trigger cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all `onEdit2` can not be used as an `onEdit` trigger unless it is installable. Therefore I would advice `onEdit` so you don't have to create the trigger yourself.
- The optimal way is to use the event handler `e` that will give you the relevant information you need regarding the cell that is edited.

I also made your code cleaner by using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check whether the edited cell is part of a list of cells.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const ts = e.source.getSheetByName("overview");
  const cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  const triggerCells = ["A5","B3","C2"];
  
  if (as.getName() == "work" && triggerCells.includes(cell)){
    let b = as.getRange("B1").getValue();
    ts.getRange("C5").setValue(b);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this code and adapt it to my needs. The reason I'm using onEdit2 is because I already have an onEdit function that works fine. I made a onEditBase.gs that just runs these two --  
function onEdit() 
{
  onEdit1() ;
  onEdit2() ;
}